# <Tag> before <Script> Tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have a page that generates the following code (example):

```
<div class="map_object">
<span> test1 </span> 
<script></script>
</div>

<div class="map_object">
<span> test2 </span>
<script></script>
</div> 

<div class="map_object"> 
<span> test3 </span>
<script></script>
</div>
```

These blocks are created by a html template file. The row with the `<span>` comes in by a placeholder (users can enter this into a text field), the rest is in the template file.

What i need is to get the content inside the `<span>` in every `<script>` (always the exact same script) Let's say block 1 should return "test1" an so on.

Do you have any idea, how to find the current `<script>` and then get the content in the `<span>` before, so this works for every block and not just the first or last one?

Comment: Why can't you use a global script that loops through all your `<span>`s and gets their value? That's the better way to do it

Comment: What do you mean by “finding the current `<script>`”? Are you asking what the “exact same script” should be so that it will access the element immediately preceding the `script` element?

Comment: I would change template to generate HTML like this: <div class="map_object"><span class="map_content"> test1 </span></div>. Then after that will add a single <script> that selects all spans with class="map_content", gets content, and does what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want..

This is pure **javascript** solution: [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/nx1h361p/1/)

```
window.onload=function(){
    var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i=0;i<span.length;i++)
    {
        span[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = span[i].innerHTML
    }
    };
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<body>
  <div class="map_object">
<span> test1 </span> 
<script> test1 </script>
</div>

<div class="map_object">
<span> test2 </span>
<script> test2 </script>
</div> 

<div class="map_object"> 
<span> test3 </span>
<script> test3 </script>
</div>
```

Have done this with **jquery** [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/q8104sbj/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        $(this).next('script').text($(this).text());
    });
})
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="map_object">
<span> test1 </span> 
<script> test1 </script>
</div>

<div class="map_object">
<span> test2 </span>
<script> test2 </script>
</div> 

<div class="map_object"> 
<span> test3 </span>
<script> test3 </script>
</div>
```

> **Note:** If this is what you what then we can do this with javascript also

Comment: Put your effort with javascript then.

Comment: I couldn't upvote your answer because I don't know exactly what the OP wanted. Also 0 should be i within the loop.

Comment: Its ok @C-linkNepal i have given my effort let OP decide it. THanks i have updated my answer `0` replace by `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest of solutions, but then again, also not the cleanest of questions:

```
<div class="map_object">
    <span> test1 </span> 
    <script>
        alert(document.currentScript.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML)
    </script>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6000xzhb/).

To clarify a bit more:

```
<div class="map_object">
    <span> test1 </span> 
    <script>
        var scriptElement = document.currentScript;
        var divElement = scriptElement.parentNode;
        var firstSpanElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('span');

        alert(firstSpanElement.innerHTML)
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobG Check the fiddle. It does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, using Jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var values= $(".map_object > span");//Get spans

   $.each(values, function( index, value ) {
     console.log(value.innerHTML);//get every span content
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @C-linkNepal He did not specify "pure javascript" or any other restriction, so i made this code :) .

Comment: He didn't tagged jQuery means just javascript only.